# Run playwright test on docker headed

Tags: javascript, reactjs, docker, testing, playwright

I have created a docker image using the following Dockerfile

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/playwright:v1.33.0-jammy

# Install Xvfb
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y xvfb x11-apps x11-xkb-utils libx11-6 libx11-xcb1

# Set the work directory for the application
WORKDIR /app

# Set the environment path to node_modules/.bin
ENV PATH /app/node_modules/.bin:$PATH

# Install NVM
RUN curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.39.0/install.sh | bash
# Activate NVM
SHELL ["/bin/bash", "-c"]
ENV NVM_DIR=/root/.nvm
RUN source $NVM_DIR/nvm.sh && nvm --version
# Install Node.js version 16.18.0
RUN source $NVM_DIR/nvm.sh && nvm install 16.18.0
# Set Node.js version 16.18.0 as the default
RUN source $NVM_DIR/nvm.sh && nvm alias default 16.18.0
# COPY the needed files to the app folder in Docker image
COPY . /app/
# Install the dependencies in Node environment
RUN source $NVM_DIR/nvm.sh && nvm use 16.18.0 && npm ci
```

I have playwright tests on my project, with `headless: false` in `playwright.config` and I want to run them on the container based on Microsoft's image.
I installed XQuartz using `brew install --cask xquartz` and allowed connections from network clients and run `xhost +localhost`, gave docker desktop access to /tmp/.X11-unix. as in [Running Playwright inside Docker containers](https://www.oddbird.net/2022/11/30/headed-playwright-in-docker/)

On XQuartz, I run:

```
docker run --rm \
        --name e2e-on-docker-container \
        -e HTTPS=false \
        -e DISPLAY=host.docker.internal:0 \
        -it -p 3000:3000 \
        -v /tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix \
        e2e-on-docker-image /bin/bash
```

to create the container

I run `npm start` and run `npx playwright test`

but got

```
Error: browserType.launch: 
     Looks like you launched a headed browser without having a XServer running.
```

Have anyone faced this issue?
Thanks for your help.

Comment: `xvfb-run npx playwright test` Refer this doc https://playwright.dev/docs/next/ci#running-headed

Comment: Thanks @Barney, 
I tried it but unfortunately doesn't work.